# Modifying Tapestry 5 Tynamo Security login form template

Tags: tapestry, tynamo

How can I override the HTML generated by  Template of Apache Tynamo?

I am currently converting my pages for use with tapestry-bootstrap and the login form looks a bit ugly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of trying to customize or reuse the provided form is way better to write your own signin page and signin form.

It's super simple, you can start by copying this:

- https://github.com/ascandroli/petstore/blob/master/src/main/java/org/amneris/petstore/pages/Signin.java
- https://github.com/ascandroli/petstore/blob/master/src/main/resources/org/amneris/petstore/pages/Signin.tml

This is just an example signin page, make sure you remove anything you don't need.

After that don't forget to tell tapestry-security that now you have your own sigin page:

```
@Contribute(SymbolProvider.class)
@ApplicationDefaults
public static void applicationDefaults(MappedConfiguration<String, Object> configuration)
{
    // Tynamo's tapestry-security (Shiro) module configuration
    configuration.add(SecuritySymbols.LOGIN_URL, "/signin");
}
```

That's it.